# ggplot2- ggcorr treats a numeric as non-numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I am using the following command using ggplot's ggcorr

I have output variable that ordinal and numeric. "grade" has five numeric value with ranking: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

```
data$grade<− as.factor(data$grade)
```

when I run the command below- it is not able to calculate the Spearman coefficient message- it is sayings "grade" is not numeric.

```
ggcorr(RedWQ[, 2:13], method = c("all.obs", "spearman"), 
       nbreaks = 4, palette = "RdGy", label = TRUE, 
       name = "Spearman correlation coeff. (ρ)", hjust = 0.66, size = 2.4)+ 
   ggtitle("Spearman Correlation coefficient Matrix")
```

I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient between continuous variables and ordinal one.

Comment: Why not let grade be numeric and run the command. It should not give any error. Whether or not it should be done (correlating a continuous variable with ordinal one) is a statistical question best suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, `grade` isn't numeric. In the code example above you explicitly convert it to a `factor` with `as.factor`. Even though it still looks like a number, it is treated as a categorical variable. As @rnso suggests, if it is an ordinal variable, why not leave it as numeric?

Comment: One can convert `grade` to `ordered(grade)` and then perform regression: `lm(outcome ~ grade, data=mydata)` to get relation between them. See https://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html for `ordered`.